# React Router with deeper paths

Tags: reactjs, typescript, routes, react-router, tsx

I am trying to get an example with React Router running.

My example has the 3 following routes:

1. (works in browser) http://0.0.0.0:8081/one
2. (fails in browser) http://0.0.0.0:8081/one/two
3. (fails in browser) http://0.0.0.0:8081/one/two/three

All routes work with `Link`, but only 1. works when typing the url in the browser. When typing i.e. the 2. route in the browser, the browser console responds the following error:

> GET http://0.0.0.0:8081/one/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Main App class:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { One } from './One';
import { Two } from './Two';
import { Three } from './Three';

export class App2 extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    public render() {
        return <BrowserRouter>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to='/one'>One</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to='/one/two'>Two</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to='/one/two/three'>Three</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/one/two/three' component={Three} />
                <Route path='/one/two' component={Two} />
                <Route path='/one' component={One} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>;
    }
}
```

Class named One:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export class One extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    public render() {
        return <div>One</div>;
    }
}
```

Class named Two:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export class Two extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    public render() {
        return <div>Two</div>;
    }
}
```

Class named Three:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export class Three extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    public render() {
        return <div>Three</div>;
    }
}
```

Command to run the app in development mode:

```
"scripts": {
    "develop": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --port 8081 --host 0.0.0.0 --config webpack.dev.config.js"
}
```

The Webpack configuration webpack.dev.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: "./src/index.html",
    filename: "./index.html"
});

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.tsx",
    output: {
        filename: "app.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debuggin webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts', and '.tsx' as resolvable exteensions.
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },

            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" },

            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "typings-for-css-module-loader", options: { modules: true, namedExport: true, camelCase: true, localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64]" }}
                ]
            },

            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /\.global.scss$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "typings-for-css-modules-loader", options: { modules: true, namedExport: true, camelCase: true, localIdentName: "[local]" }},
                    { loader: "postcss-loader", options: { plugins: function () { return [ require("autoprefixer") ]; }}},
                    { loader: "sass-loader" }
                ]
            },

            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                include: /\.global.scss$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "css-loader" },
                    { loader: "postcss-loader", options: { plugins: function () { return [ require("autoprefixer") ]; }}},
                    { loader: "sass-loader" }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        disableHostCheck: true
    },

    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns: ['dist']
        }),
        htmlPlugin
    ]
};
```

I use the following versions:

- Node v13.7.0
- "@types/react": "16.9.11",
- "@types/react-dom": "16.9.4",
- "@types/react-router-dom": "5.1.2",
- "react": "16.11.0",
- "react-dom": "16.11.0",
- "react-router-dom": "5.1.2",
- "typescript": "3.7.4",
- "webpack": "4.41.2",
- "webpack-cli": "3.3.10",
- "webpack-dev-server": "3.9.0"

I tried to follow the examples [here](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-nested-routes/).

Why does only the 1. route work? Why don't the other routes 2. and 3. work?

**Edit 1:**

Trying to use exact does not work either. The result is the same as the above mentioned:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { One } from './One';
import { Two } from './Two';
import { Three } from './Three';

export class App2 extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    public render() {
        return <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/one' component={One} />
                <Route exact path='/one/two' component={Two} />
                <Route exact path='/one/two/three' component={Three} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>;
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Trying to change the order does not work either. The result is the same as the above mentioned:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { One } from './One';
import { Two } from './Two';
import { Three } from './Three';

export class App2 extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    public render() {
        return <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/one/two/three' component={Three} />
                <Route path='/one/two' component={Two} />
                <Route path='/one' component={One} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply: the most specific route goes first. Just reverse your order.

As with most routers each one is checked in sequential order for a match.

**Edit 1:** evidence https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/primary-components

**Edit 2:** Your 404 error indicates to me that the issue is not the router but the server. Did you build the server or is webpack-dev-server a premade server for serving while you develop? I think you'll find that if you go to /one and click a  to /one/two it will actually work.

**Edit 3:** Your webpack Dev server config needs something. I don't have experience with this, but here's a doc webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputpublicpath that I think should help.

**As suggested in the comments:** The final solution is adding `publicPath: '/'` to `output` in the Webpack config.

Comment: I tried to follow your example, but it did not work. I updated the post above in **Edit 2**.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Did anything change when you tried each solution? Like which route worked?

Comment: Yes, I tried all the solutions mentioned in the above post. The web app is run using Webpack. Do I need to tell `webpack-dev-server` that I use a React Router?

Comment: Your 404 error indicates to me that the issue is not the router but the server. Did you build the server or is webpack-dev-server a premade server for serving while you develop? I think you'll find that if you go to /one and click a <Link /> to /one/two it will actually work.

Comment: I tested the above example code with `Link` and it all works perfectly. But when typing the 2. and 3. url in the browser, it fails. I use Webpack in development mode to run the app. I updated the above post.

Comment: Awesome, so your router works. Your webpack Dev server config needs something. I don't have experience with this, but here's a doc https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputpublicpath that I think should help. Try making the public path '/' or ''.

Comment: It helped indeed! Works now! The answer was in the Webpack config. Adding `publicPath: '/'` to `output` solves the problem. If you update your answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use **exact** in your `<Route/>`

Because your paths always start with `/one`, react router only matches that part, if you want go deeper, you have to tell him *exact*(ly) what you want.

```
<Route exact path='/one' component={One} />
<Route exact path='/one/two' component={Two} />
<Route exact path='/one/two/three' component={Three} />
```

Here's the link to the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool)

Comment: I tried to follow your example, but it did not work. I updated the post above in **Edit 1**.